# Infinity as sentinel in mergesort?

Tags: c

I am currently reading Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms" and I found something called a sentinel.

It's used in the mergesort algorithm as a tool to decide when one of the two merging lists is exhausted. Cormen uses the infinity symbol for the sentinels in his pseudocode and I would like to know how such an infinite value can be implemented in C.

Comment: Don't have the book to hand, but is it just used as a "larger than anything" value, so that it can be put in place of the value that would normally be taken from the list that's exhausted, and you know that value will never be selected since anything from the other side is smaller? If so, then it's just there to simplify the code - you could instead go into a different loop when one list is exhausted, that just shovels everything from the remaining list into the results. If you're merging linked lists you don't even need to shovel, you can splice the remaining list to the result and go.

Comment: "just there to simplify the code" - and maybe speed it up, by reducing the number of checks in the inner loop. I think an alternative is to use the largest value in the data set (i.e. the greater of the two ends of the two already-sorted lists being merged) as the sentinel, but I'm not certain.

Comment: I suppose I should forget about the sentinels.A loop to place the remaining list on top of the output list when one is exhausted would be enough.

Comment: Yeah, when they work sentinels can be very nifty, giving you short code that runs fast. But increasing speed by introducing bugs isn't a good trade-off, so if there isn't a sentinel value that works you just have to special-case it. You might find that you can use `INT_MAX`, provided you properly handle the case where there is one or more `INT_MAX` value in the data.

Comment: For text, the byte value 0 is a rather [in]famous sentinel.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sentinel is just a dummy value.  For strings, you might use a NULL pointer since that's not a sensible thing to have in a list.  For integers, you might use a value unlikely to occur in your data set e.g. if you are dealing with a list ages, then you can use the age -1 to denote the list.

Comment: What about if I want to sort an array of random integer values?

Comment: You just have to take your chances.  With 32bits you have a 1 in 4 billion chance of hitting the sentinel (assuming truly random numbers).  Worst case you could always go "up" a size and use a long and use something out of range.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an "infinite value" for floats, but it's not the best idea. For arrays, pass the size explicitly; for lists, use a null pointer sentinel.

Answer (score 1):

in C, when sorting an array, you usually know the size so you could actually sort a range `[begin, end)` in which `end` is one past the end of the array. E.g. `int a[n]` could be sorted as `sort(a, a + n)`.

This allow you to do two things:

- call your sort recursively with the part of the array you haven't sorted yet (merge sort is a recursive algorithm)
- use `end` as a sentinel.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the elements in your list will range from the smallest to the highest possible values for the given data type the code you are looking at won't work. You'll have to come up with something else, which I am sure can be done. I have that book in front of me right now and I am looking at the code that is causing you trouble and I have a solution that will work for you if you know the values range from the smallest for the given data type to the largest minus one at most. Open that book back up to page 31 and take a look at the Merge function. The lines causing you problems are lines 8 and 9 where the sentinel value of infinity is being used. Now, we know the two arrays are each sorted already and that we just need to merge them to get the array that is twice as big and in sorted order. This means that the largest elements in each half is at the end of the sub-arrays, and that the larger of the two is the largest in the array that is twice as big and we will have sorted once the merge function has completed. All we need to do is determine the largest of those two values, increment that value by one, and use that as our sentinel. So, lines 8 and 9 of the code should be replaced by the following 6 lines of code:

```
if L[n1] < R[n2]
  largest = R[n2]
else
  largest = L[n1]

L[n1 + 1] = largest + 1
R[n2 + 1] = largest + 1
```

That should work for you. I have a test tomorrow in my algorithms course on this stuff and I came across your post here and thought I'd help you out. The authors' use of sentinels in this book is something that has always bugged me, and I absolutely can not stand how much they are in love with recursion. Iteration is faster and in my opinion usually easier to come up with and grasp.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you don't have to check array bounds when incrementing the index in only one of the lists in the inner while loops. Hence you need sentinels that are larger than all other elements. In c++ I usually use `std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::max()`.

The C-equivalent should be macros like `INT_MAX, UINT_MAX, LONG_MAX` etc. Those are good sentinels. If you need two different sentinels, use `..._MAX` and `..._MAX - 1`

This is all assuming you're merging two lists that are ordered ascending.